# Passing variables between functions in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So ive been writing a game in swift using SpriteKit, and i'm having trouble understanding how variables are handled in swift. I'm trying to update a variable I declare at the beginning of my GameScene class again in the touchesBegan function that comes later. However, the problem i'm having is that the variable is never updated (I know this because in the didMoveToView function, the variable is used to direct the rotation of a node, and when it it supposed to be updated in the touchesBegan function, it never changes the rotation of the node).

It seems to me that I may just have a fundamental misunderstanding of how variables are delt with in Swift. I'm wondering if there is a way to update a variable that is declared early on in the Class file?

Is what i'm doing something that makes sense? Does anyone have an idea of how I can fix my situation? My code is very long and would not make sense to post all of it, so here are the important parts:

Here is where I declare the 'rotation' variable I'm trying to update and use later on.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let rotation: Int = 188400
```

Here is where the 'rotation' variable is used in the didMoveToView function:

```
let rotate = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(-188400), duration: NSTimeInterval(60000))
anchorNode.runAction(rotate)
```

Here is where I attempt to update the 'rotation' variable in the touchesBegan function:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if rotation == 188400 {

        println("Setting rotation backwards")

        let rotation = -188400

    }else{

        println("Setting rotation forwards")
        let rotation = 188400
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am just curious, what is the purpose of using 188400 for angle value ? SKAction.rotateToAngle uses radians. If you want to rotate a node by 360 degrees you can use something like : SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(2*M_PI), duration: someDuration) If you need to rotate sprite more than once, you can repeat that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you say

```
    let rotation = -188400
```

You create a *different* `rotation` variable and set its value. You are not setting the instance variable (property) `rotation`. To do *that*, omit `let`:

```
    rotation = -188400
```

What I personally like to do is write `self` whenever referring to my instance variables. So I'd write your code like this:

```
if self.rotation == 188400 {
    println("Setting rotation backwards")
    self.rotation = -188400
}
```

And so on. That use of `self` is not required, but to me it sure clarifies where this variable comes from - and it looks like such clarification is exactly what you need here!

Also, as @danielbeard points out, you're not going to be *able* to update `self.rotation` unless you declare it with `var`, not `let`.

Comment: Also, you can't update `let` declarations, so the original `rotation` value will never update.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I have one more question. Now that my variable updates, my new problem is that my SKAction does not change direction of rotation.. do you guys have a fix for this? Is there something I should change about my SKAction to make it update along with the variable

Comment: @JeffD Here on Stack Overflow it is not considered quite proper to try to mutate one question into another by adding a new question as a comment after your original question is answered. (That is called "leeching" or even "vampirism" - the questioner is continuing to suck the answerer's blood, don't you see.) Your original question _has_ been answered, and if you have a new question, you are most welcome to ask a new question! The more the merrier.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the correction. No _blood_ was meant to be sucked, but alas, my ignorance made it that way. Cheers.